# How to subscribe to multiple chat rooms using Action Cable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chat, actioncable

All examples i can find are subscribing to one single room but what if i have Room A, B and C an i (as a user) am in all of them.

This is an example with one room http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#client-server-interactions-subscriptions

Comment: What's stopping you doing just doing it three times? 

`App.cable.subscriptions.create { channel: "ChatChannel", room: "RoomA" }`

`App.cable.subscriptions.create { channel: "ChatChannel", room: "RoomB" }`

`App.cable.subscriptions.create { channel: "ChatChannel", room: "RoomC" }`

Comment: The rooms are coming from a db so i cannot hardcode them. I would have to create JS dynmically -.- There must be an easier way

Comment: You don't need to hardcode in your JavaScript file. You can get the list of rooms in your javascript.  Many ways to do that. You can either render them into js using js.erb. Or you can make a ajax call to server and receive the list of available chat rooms. What you are asking for is not a Rails or a Action Cable problem. Its basic Server Client Architecture and how it interacts using AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

Probably this is something that can help [link](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/rails-5-action-cable-with-multiple-chatroom-subscriptions/), in *.js.erb template you can dynamically create rooms as such.

```
<% Chatroom.all.each do |chatroom| %>  

  App['room' + <%=chatroom.id%>] = App.cable.subscriptions.create({channel: 'MessagesChannel', room: <%=chatroom.id%>}, {  
  received: function(data) {
   $("[data-chatroom='" + this.chatroomId + "']").removeClass('hidden')
    return $("[data-chatroom='" + this.chatroomId + "']").append(data.message);
  },

  setChatroomId: function(chatroomId) {
    this.chatroomId = chatroomId
  }
});
<% end %>
```